Why can't constructors have required type arguments?
Let's say I define the following datatype:
data fmt :* (n :: Nat) where
    Rep :: fmt -> fmt :* n

Using RequiredTypeArguments, I can define a function that takes the n parameter as a required type argument:
(*:) :: fmt -> forall n -> fmt :* n
fmt *: n = Rep fmt

But if I try to do this directly in the datatype constructor, I get an error from GHC 9.10.1:
data a :* (n :: Nat) where
    (:*) :: a -> forall n -> a :* n

    • Illegal visible, dependent quantification in the type of a term
    • In the definition of data constructor ‘:*’
   |
83 |     (:*) :: a -> forall n -> a :* n
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

What makes (:*) be problematic vis-a-vis (*:)? What would break / what would be undecidable during typechecking if GHC accepted it?

Probably that a data constructor is not only used to "pack" data together, but also to "unpack" data.

Unless I'm misunderstanding, the full proposal #281 linked in the documentation appears to allow this (see section 4, point 7).  So, maybe the answer is "they haven't gotten around to it yet."

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if this is the true motivation, but it seems like one possible motivation.
If I could write 'a' :* 3 and 'b' :* 5, I think I'd expect to also be able to write something like
case x of
    'a' :* 3 -> ...
    'b' :* 5 -> ...
    _ -> ...

That seems problematic given that at runtime, 3 and 5 don't actually exist anywhere as chunks of data.

Upvoted (but not accepted until there's an actual reference), but if this really is the reason, it's not a good reason IMO -- you don't expect to be able to pattern match on types when using e.g. https://github.com/ghc-proposals/ghc-proposals/blob/master/proposals/0448-type-variable-scoping.rst either.

@Cactus In my mind, at least, I expect to be able to pattern match on constructor calls but not on general function calls. For me, :* looks like a constructor call, while @ looks like a general function call. So I don't see the two as equivalent.
